# Firestore: sort by Firestore Timestamp causes UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get documents from my Firestore and sort them by their timestamp. The Timestamp is actually in the "firebase format" (see below)

[image: My date format]

**Code**

I tried using this code

```
const querySnapshot = await db
    .collection("placeVisits")
    .where("placeId", "==", req.params.placeId)
    .orderBy("time", "desc")
    .get();
```

but it produces
`error: (node:8356) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/...`

However, this works fine (but doesn't sort, of course)

```
const querySnapshot = await db
    .collection("placeVisits")
    .where("placeId", "==", req.params.placeId)
    .get();
```

I've no idea how to fix this or why it happens. Is it because Firestore Snapshots aren't sortable or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query on `.where("placeId", "==", req.params.placeId).orderBy("time", "desc")` requires a composite index, which is not automatically created by Firestore.

The error message contains a link. If you click the link it takes you to a page in the Firebase console to create the necessary index. All fields should be pre-populated there, so you should just have to click a button.